# How to invoke soap services from an standalone grails application

Tags: grails, ejb, glassfish-3, noclassdeffounderror

I apologize in advance cause english is not my native language. I've been having some trouble to testing an standalone client (created with grails - groovy framework) that connects with a java server application that provides ejb services.

I've tried to connect both via corba and through wsdl, both ways fail to initialice the context (`InitialContext`), cause it says i have some missing class (`NoClassDefFoundError`) when i run my app (with embedded jetty grails server). I am certain that this class should be in the classpath because i have a jar that contains it and this jar is in the classpath, as a file in the lib folder of my grails application.

This is how i try to initialice the bean to call the services:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory")
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", iProperties.getINTEGRATION_IP())
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", iProperties.getCORBA_PORT())
try{
    ctx = new InitialContext(p)
    authWS = (AdmAuthenticationRemote) ctx.lookup(AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_JNDI); // CORBA
} catch(Throwable e){
    ctx = new InitialContext(p)
    authenticationWS = (AdmAuthenticationRemote) ctx.lookup(REMOTE_CLASS_PACKAGE_NAME) // WSDL
}
```

The above code have no ';' cause groovy doesn't need them to run java code.
I tested this code in a netbeans enviroment small app and both worked. The problem comes when i try to do this in my grails app.

This is the error i get when i try to invoke any service:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/hk2/component/MultiMap
```

Of course this is not the full stack, but this is the problem cause (caused by in the stack). This class (`org.jvnet.hk2.component.MultiMap`) is contained in the file `auto-depends.jar` (a jar from glassfish). I tried to add `gf-client.jar` and `appserv-rt.jar` (glassfish jars too) to the lib so the app would invoke all the glassfish jars into the classpath but this didn't work, i found out that in standalone apps the jars containing the classes should be added manually (even thou i added just `appserv-rt.jar` in the netbeans test file and worked!) so i added this jars to my lib folder:

```
appclient.security.jar
auto-depends.jar
common-util.jar
config-api.jar
config.jar
config-types.jar
connectors-admin.jar
connectors-inbound-runtime.jar
connectors-internal-api.jar
connectors-runtime.jar
container-common.jar
deployment-common.jar
dol.jar
ejb-container.jar
ejb-internal-api.jar
ejb.security.jar
glassfish-api.jar
glassfish-corba-asm.jar
glassfish-corba-codegen.jar
glassfish-corba-csiv2-idl.jar
glassfish-corba-newtimer.jar
glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar
glassfish-corba-orbgeneric.jar
glassfish-corba-orb.jar
glassfish.jar
glassfish-naming.jar
gmbal.jar
hk2-core.jar
internal-api.jar
javax.ejb.jar
kernel.jar
management-api.jar
orb-connector.jar
orb-enabler.jar
orb-iiop.jar
security.jar
tiger-types-osgi.jar
```

Of course i also have the jar with the remote interfaces and service objects i need to access the services in the glassfish server.
Even when i do this, this error keeps happening. I'm out of ideas and stuck here with this problem and don't know how to solve it.
My question is how do i solve this exception?? Is it a grails problem?? am i not configuring some grails files??
Please any thought will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Kevin

**Updated**: I've discovered too that if i run clean and compile commands, i get this error instead of the previous one:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.hk2.component.Inhabitant`

I'm not sure why this happens but when i restart the server (without clean-compile) it gives the previous error.

Answer (score 0):

You added auto-depends.jar to the lib folder. I suppose grails WAR file should see it. But to make grails use that jar in the run-app mode you probably also need to register the dependency.
In BuildConfig.groovy add the line:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    //.....
    dependencies {
        //.....

        runtime ':glassfish-auto-depends:1'

    }
    //.....
}
```

and rename your auto-depends.jar to glassfish-auto-depends-1.jar ("-1" is a version which is required;"glassfish" is for convenience). All its dependencies should also be specified similarly.
Then execute the command:

```
grails refresh-dependencies
```

It will copy the jar to ivy cache. Then run your app - it should load the jar.

Comment: Hi @eugene82. I thank you for your quick response but it didn't worked as expected or i am doing it wrong. I changed all my jars names to have their version in them (like you said in your response) and added all of them to the `BuildConfig.groovy`. Didn't work, i'm getting the same error. Any other ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve his issue by adding all glassfish jar files (lib and modules) to the lib folder of my project, however i still have problems invoking the services.

I created another post with the details to the new problem i have.

[How to access EJB services from a grails standalone client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483725/how-to-access-ejb-services-from-a-grails-standalone-client)